# How to list Multiple Mime types files From Google drive?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

**I want to list mp3,mp4,mkv,avi,aac,wmv files from Google Drive and Now i am able to list only mp3 files but i want to list other extensions files too...**
...how can i make use of query.q = @"mimeType ='audio/mpeg' "; for multiple extensions

//I have tried this.

```
-(void)loadDriveFiles
{

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

query.q = @"mimeType ='audio/mpeg' ";




UIAlertView *alert = [GoogleUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"Loading files"

                                                         delegate:self];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,

                                                          GTLDriveFileList *files,

                                                          NSError *error) 
{       
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    if (error == nil)
    {

        if (self.driveFiles == nil) 
        {     
            self.driveFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        }

        [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];           
        [self.driveFiles addObjectsFromArray:files.items];         
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

        [GoogleUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to load files"

                                           message:[error description]

                                          delegate:self];

    }

}];
}
// Thanks In Advance
```

Comment: i need your help,i think you are good in Google Drive integration part Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288487/how-to-upload-an-image-on-google-driveerror-assertion-failure-in-gtmhttpupload

Comment: @Ravindhiran i have some clarification of Google Drive Issue..if u r free just tell me