# how to upload an image on google drive(error "Assertion failure in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading")

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive in my iOS app. I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:],
```

/Users/mac/Desktop/google-api-objectivec-client-mirror-master/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m:399

Here is the code that is highlighted when the assertion occurs:

```
NSAssert([[self downloadedData] length] == 0,
                @"unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)");
```

upload image to google drive:

```
- (void)uploadPhoto
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"];
GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
file.title = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the Google Drive iOS Quickstart";
file.mimeType = @"image/png";

UIImage   *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error)
 {
     [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
     if (error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
         [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
         [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
     }
 }];
  }
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143038/ios-using-upload-image-on-google-drive-apierror-assertion-failure-in-gtlserve, which has a valid answer.

Comment: @BurcuDogan i tried it still i am getting same error

Comment: check the post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955923/how-to-get-the-inbuild-library-for-google-drive-in-iphone-sdk/18080078#18080078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

I rectified Assertion failure in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading”) error unfortunately i forget to enable [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1#project:539121566765) Drive API

1.Create an App.

2.Go to Services, switch ON the "Drive API".

[image]

You need to enable Drive API and Drive SDK from the API Console/Services tab